# Automatically setting page style to plain when the page starts with section title

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm writing a document where I don't use page breaks before starting a new section. This means that sometimes, a section will start in the middle of the page, while other times it will start at the top of the page. When the latter happens, I use `\thispagestyle{plain}` to avoid having a header with the section title followed by the section title again right after. I have to do this manually every time a section happens start at the top of a page. Is there a way to automate this process? Just so it's clear what I'm asking for, here's how it looks like with my header done with `fancyhdr`:

[image]

The header with the section title is right next to the... section title. By adding `\thispagestyle{plain}` for that page, I get the look that I want:

[image]

But I have to do this manually every time a section just so happens to begin at the top of the page. If I section begins in the middle of the page, it's fine, like this:

[image]

It's not a huge deal to have to manually set a plain page style every time a section starts at the beginning of a page, but I just wanted to know if there's a way to automate this process.

Comment: Why,why,why? This is an established typographic tradition going back centuries.  Just select the running head type, to be distinctly different from the section title and font. Just check any book by a reputable publisher for examples. And no it is not possible to do what ou are asking using LaTeX, not easily in any case.

Comment: I mean, that wouldn't get rid of the redundancy of having the section title written twice.

Comment: Pls just post an image or two to explain your issue and provide a MWE if possible, so people can try and help you.

Comment: Done, thank you.

Comment: If you look at the pages as a spread (2-page view), the one you omitted the header will not have the rule and will look very odd. But thanks for the posting of the images. They look perfectly fine for me, without any fiddling with the running heads.

Comment: Echoing @yannisl's comments: I think you may be greatly overestimating the distraction caused by instances of the running header and a section title being adjacent.

Comment: Why do you believe the 'redundancy' to be a problem? Do you find it problematic when reading books yourself?